# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and PHP 7.2 Security Support EOL?

Tags: 18.04, php

Do I need to upgrade my PHP 7.2 to 7.4 in order to keep getting security updates for PHP if I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? I know that 18.04 is supported until April of 2023, but PHP 7.2 goes out of support in November of 2020. Does Canonical keep releasing security updates for PHP 7.2 for the entire EOL of Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ubuntu Security Team will continue to patch high-priority security vulnerabilities in the Ubuntu 18.04 -main repository pocket until 2028.

- The `php` package in Ubuntu 18.04 is in the -main pocket, so it's covered.
- 18.04 community support ends in 2023.
- [ESM](https://ubuntu.com/esm) (2023-2028) is security ONLY. No community technical support.

They won't patch ALL reported vulnerabilities; they prioritize.

They will patch common packages in -universe, those are available only to Ubuntu Pro subscribers.

Security patches won't protect any non-Ubuntu versions that you install.

Comment: What about a packages like php7.2-enchant which is listed in the universe "repository" but also listed under the security "level". Will security level items be maintained by the Ubuntu Security Team until EOL of 18.04?
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=php7.2-enchant

Comment: A lot of up-to-date php packages are in main, and those are fully supported by the Ubuntu Security Team. The Security Team has sometimes patched universe packages in the past --being good citizens-- but has never guaranteed ongoing security support for any universe package. The remit of paid engineers is main; anything extra is a bonus. Note that community volunteers can join the Security Team and help patch universe packages. Volunteers are welcome! Since there are currently not enough volunteers to handle all the CVEs in universe, users are on their own.